# Processing a long list of words. Is it possible to process it in parts simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Currently I have a list of 36 thousand words. I have a process that sets them all to lower case (easy and takes less than a second) then I decided on having a code that checks if any of these words is an anagram of another.

I use this snippet to check if they are an anagram:

```
bool is_anagram(string s1, string s2) {
    string c1(s1), c2(s2);
    if(c1.length() != c2.length())
        return 0;
    sort(c1.begin(), c1.end());
    sort(c2.begin(), c2.end());
    return c1 == c2;
}
```

Now using that code I sort the code into two containers. One being for anagrams the other being for non anagrams. Do note that since I do not want repetition I am using set instead of vector.
Here is the sorting function:

```
template<typename Container>
void sort_anagrams ( Container& unsorted, Container& yes, Container& no ) {
    for( auto x : unsorted ) {
        for ( auto y : unsorted ) {
            if ( is_anagram ( x, y ) && y != x ) {
                cout << "yes "<< x << " " << y << endl;
                yes.insert(y);
            }else {
                cout << "no "<< x << " " << y << endl;
                no.insert(y);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main just in case someone wants to use this clearly "bad' code:

```
int main() {
    set<string> initial;
    set<string> anagrams;
    set<string> trash;
    string input;
    string newline = "\n";
    ofstream os("output.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

    while(cin >> input) {
        initial.insert(input);
    }

    sort_anagrams ( initial, anagrams, trash );

    cout << "printing" << endl;

    for ( auto x : anagrams ) {
        cout << x << endl;
        if(os.good()) {
            os.write(x.c_str(), sizeof(char)*x.size() );
            os.write(newline.c_str(), sizeof(char)*newline.size() );            
        }
    }

    return 1;   
}
```

tl:dr, I am trying to run a process that I did not optimize too well and it is taking for ever. I do know there are better ways to process this list but what I wanted to learn from this is if I am able to open multiple versions of this process when I run this code and process the list in chunks.
For example this is my list as a line:
{ > [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] }

What I want to learn to do is to process it like this:

{ > [] [] [] > [] [] [] > [] [] [] > [] [] [] > [] [] [] > [] [] [] > [] [] [] }

does something along those lines exist?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about multi-threading?

Comment: If that is what its called, then yes.

Comment: You should really try to optimize `sort_anagrams` before going for parallelism. There's quite a lot of speed that can be gained there.

Comment: Sounds good, though I have some ideas maybe I can learn something here. What should I look for when trying to speed up this process?

Comment: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/
Is this along the lines of what I should understand?

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be pretty efficient (c++11, c++03 would use map<> and set<>).

No need for multi-threading since it won't add any performance. The threads would need to block each other while accessing the map of sets.

edit: updated to take word list from stdin and send anagram lists only to stdout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_set<std::string>> anagram_map;

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    while (cin) {
        string word;
        cin >> word;
        auto sorted = word;
        sort(begin(sorted), end(sorted));
        anagram_map[sorted].insert(word);
    }

    // now we have sets of distinct words indexed by sorted letters

    for (const auto& map_entry : anagram_map)
    {
        const auto& anagrams = map_entry.second;
        if (anagrams.size() > 1)
        {
            // this is the code path where we have anagrams for a set of letters
            auto sep = "";
            for (const auto& word : anagrams) {
                cout << sep << word;
                sep = " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

example of use (unix, very similar under windows):

```
$ cat > words.txt
boy yob head pane nape planet plate tape pate
<ctrl-d>

$ c++ -o anagram -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ anagram.cpp
... or if you are using gcc ...
$ g++ -o anagram -std=c++11 anagram.cpp
$ ./anagram < words.txt > anagrams.txt
$ cat anagrams.txt
pate tape
nape pane
yob boy
```

Comment: That is really cool!

My thought for multi-threading was to make multiple thread functions that were range-based. So when I lower cased the entire list that I have I would also count the words. Then split the list into equal parts and pass it into multiple range based threads. 

Though I don't know if I am even able to work with the same variable in multiple threads... Maybe if I used read only iterators?

Anyway that wont be necessary your solution works better.

Comment: @TheUnknown If there is any useful advice I can offer you, having been writing c++ for the past 20 years, it would be, "Learn the Standard Library". The STL has been designed by some of the brightest minds on the planet and solves almost every common algorithm in one or two lines of code. The other thing worth mentioning is that efficiency comes from selecting the correct algorithm (i.e. elegance), not from throwing more cpus (i.e. force) at the problem. It's like kung-fu, but without the broken bones ;-)

Comment: I will make sure to work on that. My professor likes to go really deep into how each STL algorithm works but I am only 6 weeks into my c++ course. We are currently manually rewriting some STL merge / sort functions.
Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Sorry but what would you suggest I use if I wanted to io redirect a text file for input? I cant find an simple way to do it with what I know.

Comment: Just got back to this. Thanks Richard, this was very informative!

Comment: :) my pleasure. Best of luck with the future.

Answer (score 0):

To count chars instead of sort strings can improve performance of `is_anagram()` from O(NlogN) to O(N):

```
bool is_anagram(string s1, string s2) {
    if (s1.size() != s2.size()) return false;

    int count1[256] = {0};
    int count2[256] = {0};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; s1[i] && s2[i]; i++) {
        count1[s1[i]]++;
        count2[s2[i]]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if (count1[i] != count2[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```